# how to get max value between unbounded preceding and ignoring the current row date value for a given id in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, window

I have a below pyspark dataframe:

df

```
id date             key1    
A1 2020-01-06        K1     
A1 2020-01-06        K2      
A1 2020-01-07        K3     
A1 2020-01-07        K3     
A1 2020-01-20        K3    
A2 ..
```

I need to add column last_date which is last max date for a given id ignoring the current date.

```
id date             key1    last_date
A1 2020-01-06        K1     
A1 2020-01-06        K2      
A1 2020-01-07        K3     2020-01-06 
A1 2020-01-07        K3     2020-01-06
A1 2020-01-20        K3     2020-01-07
```

I am using code but it is giving same date, how to ignore current row date?

```
unbounded_window = (
    Window.partitionBy("id")
    .orderBy("date")
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,  Window.currentRow)
)
prepared_df =df.withColumn("last_date", F.max("date").over(unbounded_window))
```

Comment: Please add df.printSchema() directly to your question. The problem is not the current row.

Comment: @user3222101 - did you get a chance to tryout the answer below? did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find when the date changes and forward fill it. Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A1','2020-01-06','K1' ),('A1','2020-01-06','K2'),\
                                  ('A1','2020-01-07','K3' ),('A1','2020-01-07','K3'),('A1','2020-01-20','K3')],schema=['id','date','key'])
w=Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')
tst_stp = tst.withColumn("date_lag",F.lag('date').over(w))
tst_dt = tst_stp.withColumn("date_chk",F.when((F.col('date')!=F.col('date_lag')),F.col('date_lag')))
#%%Forward fill

tst_res = tst_dt.withColumn('last_date',F.last('date_chk',ignorenulls=True).over(w))
```

Results:

```
tst_res.show()
+---+----------+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|      date|key|  date_lag|  date_chk| last_date|
+---+----------+---+----------+----------+----------+
| A1|2020-01-06| K1|      null|      null|      null|
| A1|2020-01-06| K2|2020-01-06|      null|      null|
| A1|2020-01-07| K3|2020-01-06|2020-01-06|2020-01-06|
| A1|2020-01-07| K3|2020-01-07|      null|2020-01-06|
| A1|2020-01-20| K3|2020-01-07|2020-01-07|2020-01-07|
+---+----------+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```scala
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+-------------------+----+
      * |id |date               |key1|
      * +---+-------------------+----+
      * |A1 |2020-01-06 00:00:00|K1  |
      * |A1 |2020-01-06 00:00:00|K2  |
      * |A1 |2020-01-07 00:00:00|K3  |
      * |A1 |2020-01-07 00:00:00|K3  |
      * |A1 |2020-01-20 00:00:00|K3  |
      * +---+-------------------+----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
      * |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
      */

    val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
    val w1 = Window.partitionBy("id", "date")
      .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    df1.withColumn("last_date", lag(col("date"), 1).over(w))
      .withColumn("last_date", min(col("last_date")).over(w1))
      .withColumn("last_date", when($"date" =!= $"last_date", $"last_date"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
      * |id |date               |key1|last_date          |
      * +---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
      * |A1 |2020-01-06 00:00:00|K1  |null               |
      * |A1 |2020-01-06 00:00:00|K2  |null               |
      * |A1 |2020-01-07 00:00:00|K3  |2020-01-06 00:00:00|
      * |A1 |2020-01-07 00:00:00|K3  |2020-01-06 00:00:00|
      * |A1 |2020-01-20 00:00:00|K3  |2020-01-07 00:00:00|
      * +---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
      */
```